# Apache2 VirtualHosts 403 Oddity

Tags: apache-2.2, configuration, virtualhost, http-status-code-403, forbidden

I'm sure this is something I should already understand, but I'm finding myself confused.

The configs in play add up to this:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
Listen 80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@domain.tld
    ServerName domain.tld
    ServerAlias *.domain.tld
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domain.tld
    <Directory /var/www/domain.tld>
        Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

DNS is working correctly.

The issue is, every variant of http://*.domain.tld/ (including http://domain.tld/) works correctly, except http://www.domain.tld/ which throws a 403.

The logs state: client denied by server configuration: /etc/apache2/htdocs

If I remove the first VirtualHost block from play, everything works as expected including http://www.domain.tld. This leads me to believe that for some reason, Apache is not considering www.domain.tld to match the second VirtualHost block, and is thereby falling back to deny all.

This seems wrong. Shouldn't the second block match www.domain.tld?

---

I've been able to resolve this, but I still don't understand why. In my original configs, I was using the real ip address of the server instead of *. Switching all instances to * as shown above made everything work as expected.

Does this have something to do with the way browsers request resources?

Comment: What is the output of `httpd -S`?

Comment: I don't seem to have that command. Ubuntu 10.10. ?

Comment: Ubuntu calls it apache2 instead of httpd

Comment: `In my original configs, I was using the real ip address of the server instead of *` - That sounds like the server had multiple IP addresses, and the dns record for www.example.com pointed to a different IP than *.example.com.

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid the wildcard for the `www` record.

Change this:

`ServerName domain.tld`

`ServerAlias *.domain.tld`

To this:

`ServerName www.domain.tld`

`ServerAlias domain.tld subdomain.domain.tld etc.domain.tld`

to see if that works. calling the Server name `www.domain.tld` for testing the wildcard to see if it's causing the problems.

Comment: I changed to just ServerName www.domain.tld ServerAlias domain.tld to simplify things. Same results unfortunately. As in, domain.tld works, www.domain.tld 403.

Comment: What does "host www.domain.tld" give back as an IP address. Is it correct ?

Comment: Yes, all DNS resolution is correct, including reverse DNS. Please see my edit above.

Comment: I haven't used wildcards like that in my Apache builds so I'm not sure but needless to say Apache can be a black art at times :-) (I've have some highly strange URL redirect issues in the past) Glad it's fixed anyway.

Comment: www is just another subdomain - there's no special meaning to it as far as a webserver is concerned. Changing the config to use explicitly named domains instead of a wildcard might indirectly fix things but would almost be a coincidence.